# xdebug, phpunit, and vim. 'uninitialized' variables in context

Tags: php, vim, phpunit, xdebug

I am using this vim plugin https://github.com/ludovicPelle/vim-xdebug with xdebug

Xdebug and the vim plugin are working fine with regular scripts. I can step through and print out variables.

When I try to step through a basic unit test, it gets to the breakpoint fine and stops, and I can step through the code ok, but I can no longer view the contents of variables.

I am trying to get this to work with a very basic unit test

```
class testClass extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testSomething()
  { 
    $a = 5;
    $b = 6;
    $c = 7;
  } 
}
```

When I step to the end of the method and try to print out the contents of $a, I get the following error.

```
13 : send =====> property_get -i 13 -d 0 -n a
13 : recv <===== {{{   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="property_get" transaction_id="13" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="300"><message><![CDATA[can not get property]]></message></error></response>
}}}
response status=break xmlns=urn:debugger_protocol_v1 xmlns:xdebug=http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug reason=ok command=property_get transaction_id=13
error code=300 : Can not get property (when the requested property to get did not exist, this is NOT used for an existing but uninitialized property, which just gets the type "uninitialised" (See: PreferredTypeNames)).
    message
        can not get property
```

When I print out the whole context the 3 variables show up as follows

```
$command = 'context_get';
 a                    = /* uninitialized */'';
 b                    = /* uninitialized */'';
 c                    = /* uninitialized */'';
```

I know that phpunit does some interesting tricks when it runs the methods of a test class, so that might be why the debugger isn't returning the variables in the method.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The error message refers to a *property*, but in your code I only see local variables. So, whatever you are trying to do, it results in a check for `testClass::$a`, not for `$a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the version of xdebug I was using, apparently this is a known issue in 2.0 which was fixed in 2.1  The virtual machine I am debugging on is ubuntu 10.04 LTS

At the time that this version of Ubuntu was released xdebug 2.1 was still a release candidate.  I compiled the most recent version of xdebug and I am able to view the variables within a method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

```
class testClass extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    $a = 0;
    $b = 0;
    $c = 0;

  function dosomething() {
    $a = 5;
    $b = 6;
    $c = 7;
  }
}
```

Or you need to include a variable file

your var.php file

<?

```
  $a = 0;
  $b = 0;
  $c = 0;
```

?>